# Why don't we say Ein KeLokeinu on Tisha BeAv?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, tisha-bav, korbanos-ketores-prayers

[Many](http://www.chabad.org.il/Articles/Article.asp?ArticleID=2356&CategoryID=736) have a custom not to say the Shir Shel Yom or Ein Kelokeinu on Tisha BeAv morning.

Why not?

Comment: Doesn't Chabad kick it up until Minchah? I know that Ashkenaz moves shir shel yom until Minchah.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt yes. Why?

Comment: Should we interrupt our aveilut? I have always thought that we postponed those portions because shsh"y is from the Bet HaMikdash and the ketoret was offered there. Of course we say korbanot in birchot hashachar, which seems to also be problematic.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - For that matter, you might be able to place the same argument / logic on why we say "Mizmor L'Todah" on Tisha B'Av. I think there's a difference between reciting the portion of the Korbanot, itself, as this was the actual service itself, vs. "Shir Shel Yom" which is "peripheral" to the service. Have to research En K'Eilokenu, as IDK the original concept of how that entered the davening in the first place.

Comment: @DanF, exactly the problem I pointed out in my theory. I still think that whatever of the later (re-)additions to the siddur could be removed are. Mizmor l'Todah is, if I recall correctly, in the siddur of the Rambam. I don't believe that either e"k or shsh"y are, however, bli neder, I will check my geonic and rishonic references before the taanit to support my argument

Answer (score 4):

[Nit'ei Gavriel, Hilchot Bein HaMetzarim 62 fn 7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46440&st=&pgnum=25) quotes an explanation from Responsa Zera Emet as to the common custom to omit *shir shel yom* and *ein kelokeinu* from *shacharit* and instead to recite them at *mincha*.

Essentially, one would be permitted to recite them at *shacharit*, despite the prohibition of learning Torah on Tisha B'Av, as they fall under the category of *seder hayom* (daily recitations).

However, the custom developed not to recite them, due to the strength of the *aveilut* in the morning (in the same way as the custom is not to wear *tefillin* nor sit on a regular chair until after midday).

So, they are not said in the morning owing to the prohibition of Torah study on Tisha B'Av, although they do not technically fall under the formal scope of the prohibition (which is why they can be recited in the afternoon).